# Comment python script programatically

Tags: python

My script file has lots of classes:

```
def func1():
  ...

class IPSEC(aetest.Testcase):
  ....

class IPSEC_DPI(aetest.Testcase):
  ....

class IPSEC_FNF(aetest.Testcase):
  ....
   .
   .
more classes
   .
   .
class all_results(aetest.Testcase):
  ....
```

`all_results` is the last class.

I need to create a function that accepts the class name and file path of the script above and comment that particular class. all_results will never be commented. I know its weird but thats the requirement as of now.

I created the function below, but it fails. Any other short method to achieve the same?

```
def comment_lines(file_name, profile):
    lines = open(file_name, 'r').readlines()
    start=None
    end=None
    i=0
    print(f"looking for class {profile}(aetest.Testcase):")
    for i in range(0, len(lines)):
        if f"class {profile}(aetest.Testcase):" in lines[i]:
            start=i
            break
        i+=1
    for i in range(start+1, len(lines)):
        if f"class " in lines[i]:
            end=i-2
            break
        i+=1
    for i in range(start, end+1):
        lines[i] = "#" + lines[i]
    out = open(file_name, 'w')
    out.writelines(lines)
    out.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this?

```py
def comment_lines(file_name, profile):
    with open(file_name, 'r') as f:
        lines = f.readlines()

    profile = f"class {profile}(aetest.Testcase):"
    comment = False
    print(f"looking for {profile}")
    for i in range(len(lines)):
        if  lines[i].strip() == profile in lines[i]:
             comment = True
        elif comment and lines[i].startswith("class"):
             comment = False
    
        if comment:
             lines[i] = '# ' + lines[i]
    
    with open(file_name, 'w') as f:
        f.writelines(lines)
```

---

Some tips that I should mention:

1. You don't need to define the variable you want to use in a for-loop before like other languages (C, C++, Java, etc) Python will do it for you!
2. Use `with` to open a file and read/write in them as it will close and save them automatically.
3. Try doing everything in one loop as it is much faster!
4. Use or update variables like `profile` before loop to make the loop faster!

Answer (score 2):

Do It The Right Way™ with `libcst` and [the structural pattern matching feature](https://peps.python.org/pep-0636/) introduced in Python 3.10. If updating to 3.10 is not a choice, `if`/`elif`/`else` blocks can be used instead, but that is an exercise for the reader.

```
import libcst as cst


# Naming is hard
class ClassFile:
  def __init__(self, file_name: str):
    self._file_name = file_name

  def comment_out(self, class_name):
    with open(self._file_name, 'r+') as file:
      code = file.read()
      tree = cst.parse_module(code)

      # .visit() calls the visitor's methods
      # every time it visits and leaves a node.
      new_tree = tree.visit(ClassDefCommenter(tree, class_name))
      
      file.seek(0)
      file.write(new_tree.code)
```

The visitor we need is an instance of a subclass of `cst.CSTTransformer`:

```py
class ClassDefCommenter(cst.CSTTransformer):

  def __init__(self, module: cst.Module, class_name: str):
    self._module = module
    self._class_name = class_name
  
  def leave_ClassDef(self, node: cst.ClassDef, updated_node: cst.ClassDef) -> cst.CSTNode:
    '''
    This method takes in two argument:
    - The original node, and
    - a deep copy of that node (to be inserted to the new tree).

    We need to find a class definition block whose:
    - .name is the given class name
    - .bases is a sequence with only one argument: 'aetest.Testcase'
    '''

    match node:
      case cst.ClassDef(
        name = cst.Name(value = self._class_name),
        bases = [
          cst.Arg(
            value = cst.Attribute(
              value = cst.Name(value = 'aetest'),
              attr = cst.Name(value = 'Testcase')
            )
          )
        ]
      ):
        # Replace any such block with a multiline string
        # containing the original source code.
        return cst.SimpleString(
          value = f"'''{self._module.code_for_node(node)}'''"
        )
      case _:
        # Else, do nothing.
        return updated_node
```

For simplicity and ease of explanation, I used multiline string syntax instead of comment. You might want to escape nested triple quotes, if any.

Try it:

```py
ClassFile('filename.py').comment_out('IPSEC')
```

This file:

```py
class aetest:

  class Testcase:
    ...

def func1():
  ...

class IPSEC(aetest.Testcase):
  ...
    
class IPSEC_DPI(aetest.Testcase):
  ...

class IPSEC_FNF(aetest.Testcase):
  ...

class all_results(aetest.Testcase):
  ...
```

...will be modified to:

```py
class aetest:

  class Testcase:
    ...

def func1():
  ...
'''
class IPSEC(aetest.Testcase):
  ...
''' 
class IPSEC_DPI(aetest.Testcase):
  ...

class IPSEC_FNF(aetest.Testcase):
  ...

class all_results(aetest.Testcase):
  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Another implementation using a tri-state flag `found`:

```
def comment_lines(file_name, profile):
    with open(file_name) as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
    with open(file_name, 'w') as f:
        found = 0
        for line in lines:
            if found == 0 and f"class {profile}(aetest.Testcase):" in line:
                line = '#' + line
                found = 1
            elif found == 1:
                if 'class' in line:
                    found = 2
                else:
                    line = '#' + line
            f.write(line)
```

And another implementation, slightly longer, but that doesn't comment blank lines after the end of the target class definition (it still comments blank lines *inside* said definition); this is achieved by bufferizing blank lines and writing them to the file only after a not-blank line has been encountered:

```
def comment_lines(file_name, profile):
    with open(file_name) as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
    with open(file_name, 'w') as f:
        found = False
        buffer = []
        for line in lines:
            if f"class {profile}(aetest.Testcase):" in line:
                found = True
            elif found:
                if not line.strip():
                    buffer.append(line)
                    continue
                elif 'class' in line:
                    found = False
            for l in buffer:
                f.write('# '*found + l)
                buffer = []
            f.write('# '*found + line)
```

Comment: @Ashenguard's implementation is actually simpler in regards to the use of a simple flag